# How to mock CriteriaQuery.where() followed by order by

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, predicate

I have the class where

```
CriteriaQuery<Entity> cq=criteriaQuery.root<Entity>();
.....
.....
cq.where(predictes.toArray(new Predicate[0])).orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get(ENTITY.COLUMNNAME))
```

I need to mock this line , unable to pass this line.
I tried

```
mockito.doReturn(Path).when(root).get(....);
mockito.doReturn(Order).when(criteriabuilder).asc(Path);
```

This also not helping me to acheive

Comment: I am not convinced from the value of a test that mocks details of the `CriteriaQuery` construction. I think that you should have a higher abstraction for CriteriaQuery usage and mock this abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to mock repository method instead of CriteriaQuery construction, with something like this in your mock class:

```
    @Mock
    CustomRepository customRepository;
    Mockito.when(customRepository.findEntity(Matchers.any()))
            .thenReturn(entity);
```

Comment: Does the question say that Spring (Data JPA) is being used?

Comment: No, the question doesn't say that it uses Spring(Data JPA).

Comment: So why are you answering about spring data jpa jparepository?

Comment: In my answer, the definition of `CustomRepository` is agnostic to implementation i.e `findEntitiy` method can either have implementation with Spring Data or as asked, with Criteria.